# For making a database free app for iOS using Core Data and dropbox, google drive and other storage providers?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, logic

I'm developing an iOS application which allows the user to take photos, record videos and take notes and show them in timeline view. I don't wanna use any backend or database support.
I've to implement this using Google Drive, Dropbox and other storage providers.
Can you suggest me logic for maintaining the data and relationship between them. Also I need suggestion grouping the images based on location, I'm really confused because am a fresher to development.
Thanks.

Comment: why not use a database?
You're going to end up storing as hidden file somewhere on Google Drive or Dropbox, and use that to maintain your own index to the stored assets.  Sounds like you will be inventing a poor copy of a database ...

Comment: I don't want to use a database now coz I don't want to invest in my project as of now @Russell

Comment: You can use Firebase (for example) without any charges if you have less than 20,000 uploads per day.  Kudos if you're expecting more traffic than that :-)